# Can this person use the tax status of qualifying widow on her 2020 income tax return

Tags: united-states, income-tax

Please consider a case where I couple, living in the US, has two grown kids (a son and a daughter) (over 40) and the father dies in 2019. The mother inherits the husband’s assets. The couple normally files a joint income tax return.

The son has done well and is self-supporting. The daughter works very part time and has no assets. The mother is planning on supporting the daughter in 2020. The mother and the daughter have same permanent residence. Can the mother using the qualifying widow tax status on her 2020 income tax return?

I believe the answer is yes.

Comment: "Qualifying window"?  But apparently she could be a qualifying WIDOW, assuming the daughter meets the tests for being a dependent: ttps://www.efile.com/qualifying-widow-widower-tax-filing-status/ https://www.irs.gov/faqs/filing-requirements-status-dependents/dependents/dependents-2

Comment: @jamesqf I think you are telling me that she can use the qualifying widow because the daughter is a qualifying relative.

Comment: If the daughter earns less than $4200, she counts as a qualifying relative for the mother to file as Head of Household, as long as other conditions are met too: https://www.efile.com/qualifying-relative-child-friend-parent-dependent-exemption-test/ and https://www.efile.com/irs-head-of-household-tax-filing-status/#qualifying-person

Comment: @stanri: but this Q is not about HoH. HoH is better than filing single, but QW is even better than HoH -- QW gives you the same brackets, rates and rules as MFJ, but only for two years after the year of death (for the year of death itself you can file _as_ MFJ). And even for HoH the $4,200 limit only applies to a qualifying relative OTHER than a child -- this Q is a child.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 my comment was in response to another comment which isn't there now, where the OP says the child is too old to be a Q child (and HoH does still allow for children to be a Q dependant if they don't qualify as as Q child by age, as example 1 on this page shows: https://www.efile.com/qualifying-relative-child-friend-parent-dependent-exemption-test/)

Comment: @Bob, what is the daughters age, and is she a student?

Comment: The daughter is around 50 years of age and is not a student.

Comment: @stanri: ah, I missed that. It's actually (still) in the Q: 'over 40'. Sorry. If I delete my comment will that help or just make it more confusing?!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the supported daughter could qualify the widow.

Let's start with dependents. Dependents can be qualifying children (QC) or qualifying relatives (QR). The QC criteria, among others, require the child to be under the ages of 19 (or 24 if a student) and has no income limit. The QR criteria are much broader, except that you must make under an income threshold around $4000 (depends on the year).

So let's look at the widow test. Publication 501's language for the widow test is excerpted as follows: "3. You have a child or stepchild (not a foster child) whom you can claim as a dependent or could claim as a dependent except that, for 2017: a. The child had gross income of $4,050 or more"

So you must have:

- A child or stepchild
- Who you could claim as a dependent (whether or not you did)

That does not require that your child qualify as a Qualifying Child, just that they qualify as a dependent. You'll also note that this bit about the income limit wouldn't make sense if it was limited to Qualifying Children because there is no income limit for QC. I believe, if I'm reading that rather confusing sentence properly, that you can ignore the income limit for the purpose of determining whether a qualifying relative (who must be a child or stepchild) has dependent status. (Though of course you can't actually claim them if they make too much - but you can qualify as a widow based on it.)

I'm clarifying this exact question with a tax expert, but I think "they have to be a Qualifying Child" is demonstrably wrong due to the mention of the income limit, which wouldn't apply.